# How can I click on the element which is moving using webdriver io?

Tags: npm, webdriver-io

I want to click on the element which is moving on webpage. How can I click on it?

I am using webdriver io

Comment: I assume you can just use a normal selector to get the element and then call `click` on it no? What have you tried? What errors do you see?

Comment: thanks for the reply. It is now resolve. there was error for the selector.

Comment: If this is no longer a relevant question, then consider closing it Radha. All the best!